# Julia: how to use ccall to access a function that returns an array

Tags: c++, arrays, c, julia

I've read through https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/ several times, but I am still struggling to deal with a function that returns an array.  Suppose we have a C++ function:

```
double* get_array() {
    double * my_array = new double[3] {1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
    return my_array;
}
```

declared `extern "C"` so that we can access it via Julia.  What's the best way to write a Julia function that calls this function?  (The Julia function should take no parameters, and return a `Vector{Float64}`.)

Please only provide answers using just base Julia functionality like ccall (no packages such as Cxx.jl please).

Also, is there a good way to do deal with a C++ function that returns an std::array (other than just wrapping it in a C++ function that returns the `.data()` of the array, and then proceeding as above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C++ are just pointers to the memory address of the first element of the given type. In your example, you return a `double*`, so [the Return Type Translation guide](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#ccall-/-@cfunction-return-type-translation-guide) says:

- T*

  - If the memory is already owned by Julia, or is an isbits type, and is known to be non-null:

    - Ref{T}, where T is the Julia type corresponding to T
    - a return type of Ref{Any} is invalid, it should either be Any (corresponding to jl_value_t*) or Ptr{Any} (corresponding to jl_value_t**)
    - C MUST NOT modify the memory returned via Ref{T} if T is an isbits type
- If the memory is owned by C:

  - Ptr{T}, where T is the Julia type corresponding to T

In your example, C owns the memory because it is declared as a heap-allocated pointer in the function. Therefore the `ccall` to the function will return `Ptr{T}`. The [Bits Types conversion guide](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#man-bits-types) says that `double` maps to the alias `Cdouble`, which is just a `Float64`. So your `ccall` would look like this:

```
arr = ccall((:get_array, "libfoo"), Ptr{Cdouble}, ())
```

To convert that `Ptr{Cdouble}` to a `Vector{Float64}`, you have to know the length of the array. In your example, that is 3, so following the [Accessing Data Through a Pointer guide](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#Accessing-Data-through-a-Pointer), you would use something like this to convert the array:

```
jl_arr = unsafe_wrap(Array{Float64}, arr, 3, own=false)
```

Of course, creating a bare pointer to memory allocated within a function call and handing that outside the function without any array length information is not a particularly safe way of writing C++ functions. You might consider options like:

1. Allocating a `Vector{Float64}` in Julia and passing a `Ref` and length as two arguments to your `get_array` function; or
2. Defining a `struct` in C that holds the array pointer and length information and return that instead of the bare `double *`.

If you are interested, option #1 has an example in the [C Wrapper Examples](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#C-Wrapper-Examples) section. For your example use, you would redefine your C function like this:

```
void get_array(double *arr /* or arr[] */, std::size_t size) {
    for int i = 0; i < size; ++i {
        arr[i] = (i + 1) / 10. + i + 1; // or whatever
    }
}
```

Then in your Julia program, you would first create the `Vector{Float64}` or `Vector{Cdouble}` you want to pass, then because Julia owns the memory, pass a `Ref` of the `Vector` to `ccall`, like this:

```
vec = Vector{Cdouble}(undef, 3)
ccall((:get_array, "libfoo"), Cvoid, (Ref{Cdouble}, Csize_t), vec, length(vec))
```

Note that `Base.cconvert` takes care of getting the reference to `vec` for you.

The `gethostname()` example in [Calling C and Fortran Code](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#Calling-C-and-Fortran-Code) is a useful reference for this kind of call signature as well. They use a `Ptr{Cdouble}` as the first argument, but the gist is the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  However, this solution gives me an error.  In the first line, should `Cdouble` actually be `Ptr{Float64}` or `Ptr{Cdouble}`?

Comment: P.S. Assuming the above issue is addressed and a working solution presented, I think this is a good answer, and I would accept it.  However, if you have a minute after addressing the issue above, I think the answer could be outstanding if you gave a minimal example showing how to do the alternative option #1 (allocating in Julia first, and using a `Ref` and length) that you mentioned above.  Giving this example might also trivialize the other part of the question about how to properly do this for a `std::array` (that part of the question is currently unanswered above).

Comment: I think because `std::array` has no public data members, Julia can't readily access the data elements of the struct directly. You can call `arr.data()` to get a pointer to the beginning of the data in memory and `arr.size()` to get the size of the array, though, which opens up the possibility of using option #2 with your own struct definition.

Comment: And thanks for pointing out that error, @MindSeeker. I updated the example in the answer.